# asyncio project. What am I missing?

Tags: sockets, python-3.x, asyncsocket, python-asyncio

I've been working on a client for this chat server but I am running into a bit of a challenge. The server uses Python's 3.4RC1 asyncio module.

Behavior:

My client connects. My second client connects. Either can send messages to the server BUT, the server is not broadcasting them as it should in a normal public chat room.

User1: Hello. ***Presses Enter.***

User2 does not see it.

User2: Anyone there? ***Presses Enter.***

User2 sees User1: Hello. and User2: Anyone there?

Just... strange. Not sure what I'm missing.

Here are the files. Give it a try.

Server:

```
from socket import socket, SO_REUSEADDR, SOL_SOCKET
from asyncio import Task, coroutine, get_event_loop

class Peer(object):
    def __init__(self, server, sock, name):
        self.loop = server.loop
        self.name = name
        self._sock = sock
        self._server = server
        Task(self._peer_handler())

    def send(self, data):
        return self.loop.sock_send(self._sock, data.encode('utf-8'))

    @coroutine
    def _peer_handler(self):
        try:
            yield from self._peer_loop()
        except IOError:
            pass
        finally:
            self._server.remove(self)

    @coroutine
    def _peer_loop(self):
        while True:
            buf = yield from self.loop.sock_recv(self._sock, 1024)
            if buf == b'':
                break
            self._server.broadcast('%s: %s' % (self.name, buf.decode('utf-8')))

class Server(object):
    def __init__(self, loop, port):
        self.loop = loop
        self._serv_sock = socket()
        self._serv_sock.setblocking(0)
        self._serv_sock.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self._serv_sock.bind(('',port))
        self._serv_sock.listen(5)
        self._peers = []
        Task(self._server())

    def remove(self, peer):
        self._peers.remove(peer)
        self.broadcast('Peer %s quit!' % (peer.name,))

    def broadcast(self, message):
        for peer in self._peers:
            peer.send(message)

    @coroutine
    def _server(self):
        while True:
            peer_sock, peer_name = yield from self.loop.sock_accept(self._serv_sock)
            peer_sock.setblocking(0)
            peer = Peer(self, peer_sock, peer_name)
            self._peers.append(peer)
            self.broadcast('Peer %s connected!' % (peer.name,))

def main():
    loop = get_event_loop()
    Server(loop, 1234)
    loop.run_forever()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Client:

```
# import socket
from socket import *
# form socket import socket, bind, listen, recv, send

HOST = 'localhost' #localhost / 192.168.1.1
# LAN - 192.168.1.1
PORT = 1234
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)# 98% of all socket programming will use AF_INET and SOCK_STREAM
s.connect((HOST, PORT))

while True:
    message = input("Your Message: ")
    encoded_msg = message.encode('utf-8')
    s.send(encoded_msg)
    print('Awaiting Reply..')
    reply = s.recv(1024)
    decoded_reply = reply.decode('utf-8')
    decoded_reply = repr(decoded_reply)
    print('Received ', decoded_reply)

s.close()
```

Here's the non threaded server code I wrote. works great but ONLY between 2 people. How could this code be updated to broadcast every message received to all clients connected?

```
# import socket
from socket import *
# form socket import socket, bind, listen, recv, send

HOST = 'localhost' #localhost / 192.168.1.1
# LAN - 192.168.1.1
PORT = 1234
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM) # 98% of all socket programming will use AF_INET and SOCK_STREAM
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(5) # how many connections it can receive at one time
conn, addr = s.accept() # accept the connection
print('Connected by', addr) # print the address of the person connected

while True:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    decoded_data = data.decode('utf-8')
    data = repr(decoded_data)
    print('Received ', decoded_data)
    reply = input("Reply: ")
    encoded_reply = reply.encode('utf-8')
    conn.sendall(encoded_reply)
    print('Server Started')
conn.close()
```

Comment: I get an error: `AttributeError: '_WindowsSelectorEventLoop' object has no attribute 'sock_send'`, and also `buf` in `_peer_loop` isn’t defined.

Comment: Ops! I had 3 lines of code commented out in the server code. Copy, Paste, Give it another try.

Comment: The `AttributeError` still persists for me.

Comment: You must have the latest python installed. 3.4RC1

Comment: Got it running by replacing `self.loop.sock_send` with [`self.loop.sock_sendall`](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.BaseEventLoop.sock_sendall).

Comment: Damn sendall... Cool. Give it try.

Comment: Try adding `print("sending message %s" % message)` at the beginning of your `broadcast()` method and you'll see that the server functions correctly. The problem is that each client blocks waiting for user input, so it doesn't check for new chat messages until *after* a user inputs something. Using threads on the client is overkill and unnecessary if your goal is to learn how to use asyncio. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/25352042/122763 for an example of reading from stdin in an event loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, let’s think about what your client does. You ask for a message to send, blocking for user input. Then you send that message and receive whatever there is at the server. Afterwards, you block again, waiting for another message.

So when client A sends a text, client B is likely blocking for user input. As such, B won’t actually check if the server sent anything. It will only display what’s there *after* you have sent something.

Obviously, in a chat, you don’t want to block on user input. You want to continue receiving new messages from the server even if the user isn’t sending messages. So you need to separate those, and run both asynchronously.

I haven’t really done much with `asyncio` yet, so I don’t really know if this can be nicely done with it, but you essentially just need to put the reading and sending into two separate concurrent tasks, e.g. using threads or `concurrent.futures`.

---

A quick example of what you could do, using `threading`:

```
from socket import *
from threading import Thread

HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 1234
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))

def keepReading ():
    try:
        while True:
            reply = s.recv(1024).decode()
            print('Received ', reply)
    except ConnectionAbortedError:
        pass

t = Thread(target=keepReading)
t.start()

try:
    while True:
        message = input('')
        s.send(message.encode())
except EOFError:
    pass
finally:
    s.close()
```

Comment: ahh... threads. I have no experience with threads. But... I can post another server code. Perhaps you could provide a "thread example" based on it? Updating original post. Hang on.

Comment: @Vini Well, you could just use `concurrent.futures`. There’s a simple example for the [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor). In your case, you would then have one function that will have an infinite loop reading from the socket, and another function with an infinite loop waiting for user input and sending that then.

Comment: I... am unable to visualize things in such clear manner. But i'll keep reading. Feel free to beat e to it.

Comment: Hmmm... it seems to give out error.
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Comment: It works for me… are you sure your server is running? Did you fix the `sock_sendall` part in the server code?

Comment: Wow... Awesome! I guess it helps if I don't think your code was actually a server...

Comment: Just a final quick question. I've read somewhere that spawning a few threads may eventually cause the computer to get slow.. I've read something about putting a thread to sleep while it waits to do something. Is this code prone to eventually slow down?

Comment: Both `socket.recv` and `input` block the execution, so no processing actually happens during that time. At any time, the operating system may decide to reschedule threads so those that actually need processing power get prioritized. So no, unless you spawn a large number of threads, this won’t be an issue at all.

Comment: Using threads defeats the purpose of writing this with asyncio.