# Chat server ready to receive at all times?

Tags: python, sockets

I'm sorry that this is probably a re-post of some description, however I couldn't find a question that gave me the answer I need.

I'm coding a basic chat server in Python, and I can get the clients to interact perfectly, however, the clients will only receive data after they have sent some.

I need the clients to be able to receive data at any point.

Does anyone have an example of some code I could look at to see how this could be done, or just a worded explanation of how to do it?

Comment: Hi! I think you're talking about polling? You can use some JS to poll every second, or shorter, depending on your needs. Another thing to look into is websockets. There's a bit of discussion here: http://flask.pocoo.org/mailinglist/archive/2011/12/30/websockets/ regarding Flask, but if you do a quick search for "python websockets" you'll be able to gather some more information.

Comment: The issue I'd have with polling is I'm using a windows system. From what I understand, Windows doesn't work well with the "select" module

Comment: This sounds somewhat similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21816533/asyncio-project-what-am-i-missing). Maybe my answer there will help you too.

Comment: @QuarterGeekster that's wrong, select works with sockets on Windows just fine.

Answer (score 1):

That's a really long story.

You could start by looking at Python's [`asynchat`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/asynchat.html). Next, you might consider looking at [Twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/).

Comment: I'm using python 3.3.3, so Twisted won't work, as that only works with 2.7. Have you got any examples of using asynchat?

Comment: @QuarterGeekster There is an example on asynchat's page (it's not a chat, but an HTTP handler though, but it's pretty clear). Google also gave me this chat example: http://www.grantjenks.com/wiki/random/python_asynchat_chat_example