# aysncio cannot read stdin on Windows

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, asynchronous, stdin

I'm trying to read stdin asynchronously on Windows 7 64-bit and Python 3.4.3

I tried this inspired by an [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25351999/what-file-descriptor-object-does-python-asyncios-loop-add-reader-expect#answer-25352042):

```
import asyncio
import sys


def reader():
    print('Received:', sys.stdin.readline())


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
task = loop.add_reader(sys.stdin.fileno(), reader)
loop.run_forever()
loop.close()
```

However, it raises an `OSError: [WInError 100381] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket`.

Could a file-like object like `stdin` be wrapped in a class to give it the API of a socket? I have [asked this question separately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31511563/file-to-socket-adapter-in-python), but if the solution is simple please answer here.

Assuming that I cannot wrap a file-like object to make it a socket, I tried using streams as inspired by [this gist](https://gist.github.com/nathan-hoad/8966377):

```
import asyncio
import sys


@asyncio.coroutine
def stdio(loop):
    reader = asyncio.StreamReader(loop=loop)
    reader_protocol = asyncio.StreamReaderProtocol(reader)
    yield from loop.connect_read_pipe(lambda: reader_protocol, sys.stdin)


@asyncio.coroutine
def async_input(loop):
    reader = yield from stdio(loop)
    line = yield from reader.readline()
    return line.decode().replace('\r', '').replace('\n', '')


@asyncio.coroutine
def main(loop):
    name = yield from async_input(loop)
    print('Hello ', name)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main(loop))
loop.close()
```

And that raises a `NotImplementedError` in `asyncio.base_events._make_read_pipe_transport`

Please advise how to read `stdin` using `asyncio` on Windows...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `NotImplementedError` exception is raised because the [connect pipes coroutines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#connect-pipes) are not supported by the `SelectorEventLoop`, which is the default event loop set on `asyncio`. You need to use a [`ProactorEventLoop`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloops.html#asyncio.ProactorEventLoop) to support pipes on Windows. However, it would still not work because apparently the `connect_read_pipe` and `connect_write_pipe` functions doesn't support `stdin`/`stdout`/`stderr` or files in Windows as Python 3.5.1.

One way to read from `stdin` with an asynchronous behavior is using a thread with the loop's `run_in_executor` method. Here is a simple example for reference:

```
import asyncio
import sys

async def aio_readline(loop):
    while True:
        line = await loop.run_in_executor(None, sys.stdin.readline)
        print('Got line:', line, end='')

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(aio_readline(loop))
loop.close()
```

In the example the function `sys.stdin.readline()` is called within another thread by the `loop.run_in_executor` method. The thread remains blocked until `stdin` receives a linefeed, in the mean time the loop is free to execute others coroutines if they existed.

Comment: Hm, but this seems to be blocking, right? Any way to get this non-blocking?

Comment: @masi `aio_readline()` is non-blocking, the program by itself is blocking by using `run_until_complete()`. But you should only use the `await loop.run_in_executor(None, sys.stdin.readline)` part in your application. The rest is just to exemplify the usage.