# File to socket adapter in python

Tags: python, sockets, asynchronous, serial-port, stdin

I want to use the [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) library on Windows to read file-like objects (such as `sys.stdin` and [serial ports](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyserial)).

However, `asyncio` on Windows [expects readable objects to be sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31510190/aysncio-cannot-read-stdin-on-windows).

Is it possible to write an adapter class to wrap a file-like object with the API of a socket so that I could use `stdin` and serial ports with `asyncio`?

If so, please could you give an example because I've never used sockets before?

Answer (score 2):

### Short answer

No and maybe yes.

### Long answer

You can't just wrap a file-like object as a socket, or vice-versa, and expect it to work. `asyncio` is using system calls under the hood to do its async magic and `stdin` is `stdin` from the system's point of view no mater how much you wrap it. When using the default `SelectorEventLoop` it uses one of the [select](https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html)-like system calls. On Windows it uses the [`select`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html#select.select) system call, which does **not** support anything but sockets.

So, `select` sucks on windows. Is there another option? Yes. On Windows, and only Windows, there is another API for doing async operations called `IOCP (I/O Completion Ports)`. It's a `"notify-on-completion"` type multiplexer as opposed to the `select` based `"notify-when-ready"` type multiplexers. The API is much more complicated than doing a simple `select` call on a file, but fortunately `asyncio` has *some* support for it already.

The `ProactorEventLoop` uses IOCP on Windows and it should theoretically supports reading from `stdin`. I don't have access to a Windows machine so I can't test this, but give this a go:

```
# vim: filetype=python3 tabstop=2 expandtab

import asyncio as aio
import os
import sys

if os.name == "nt":
  proactor_loop = aio.ProactorEventLoop()
  aio.set_event_loop(proactor_loop)

@aio.coroutine
def main(loop):
  stdin_reader = aio.StreamReader()
  stdin_transport, stdin_protocol = yield from loop.connect_read_pipe(
    lambda: aio.StreamReaderProtocol(stdin_reader),
    sys.stdin
  )

  line = yield from stdin_reader.read()
  print(line.strip().decode("utf-8"))

  stdin_transport.close()

loop = aio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main(loop))
loop.close()
```

And run the equivalent of this on Windows:

```
$ echo blha blha blha | python test.py
blha blha blha
```

If this works, then at least you can do async `stdin` on Windows. And then you could try something similar for `stdout/stderr` or perhaps even serial ports.

If all else fails, you could always simulate async behaviour by wrapping blocking calls in threads using the `loop.run_in_executor` coroutine:

```
yield from loop.run_in_executor(None, sys.stdin.readline)
```

Comment: Example doesn't work unfortunatelly :( Fails at "yield from stdin_reader.read()" part with "OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid" error

Comment: Ahh, I was afraid it wouldn't work. --- Using a thread pool (i.e. `run_in_executor`) should work though and should be sufficient for most use cases.

Comment: Rather than use `sys.stdin`, would `os.fdopen(sys.stdin.fileno(), 'rb')` work? Pass in a new binary file object for the file handle, not the textiowrapper.