# Listen to keypress with asyncio

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

Can somebody provide a sample of code which listen to keypress in nonblocking manner with asynio and put the keycode in console on every click?

It's not a question about some graphical toolkit

Comment: Do you want to wait for data on standard input, or is your question about a graphical toolkit? In the latter case, what graphical toolkit?

Comment: no graphical toolkit just a console application

Comment: Here you can find an example for reading from stdin an writing to stdout: https://gist.github.com/nathan-hoad/8966377 -- In that example, stdin is line-buffered (i.e. you read line-by-line). You want an unbuffered stdin (so that you can read char-by-char)

Comment: thanks! I guess it is similar to the thing which I'm looking for

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini consider posting an answer

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini
Is there a new version that doesn't use yield?

Comment: sshkeyboard, https://sshkeyboard.readthedocs.io/en/2.0.0/reference.html
is very very simple
just make sure you use sshkeyboard.listen_keyboard_manual and put it on the event loop yourself

Answer (score 18):

So the link provided by Andrea Corbellini is a clever and thorough solution to the problem, but also quite complicated.  If all you want to do is prompt your user to enter some input (or simulate raw_input), I prefer to use the much simpler solution:

```
import sys
import functools
import asyncio as aio

class Prompt:
    def __init__(self, loop=None):
        self.loop = loop or aio.get_event_loop()
        self.q = aio.Queue()
        self.loop.add_reader(sys.stdin, self.got_input)

    def got_input(self):
        aio.ensure_future(self.q.put(sys.stdin.readline()), loop=self.loop)

    async def __call__(self, msg, end='\n', flush=False):
        print(msg, end=end, flush=flush)
        return (await self.q.get()).rstrip('\n')

prompt = Prompt()
raw_input = functools.partial(prompt, end='', flush=True)

async def main():
    # wait for user to press enter
    await prompt("press enter to continue")

    # simulate raw_input
    print(await raw_input('enter something:'))

loop = aio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
loop.close()
```

EDIT:  I removed the loop parameter form `Queue` as it is removed in 3.10.

Also, these days I use structured concurrency (trio), and if anyone is curious this is pretty easy to do in trio:

```
import trio, sys
  
async def main():
    async with trio.lowlevel.FdStream(sys.stdin.fileno()) as stdin:
            async for line in stdin:
                if line.startswith(b'q'):
                    break
                print(line)


trio.run(main)
```

Comment: @wolfdawn, unfortunately windows does not support reading from `stdin` in an asychronous way, see (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31510190/aysncio-cannot-read-stdin-on-windows) for more info

Comment: Running this code results in `DeprecationWarning: The loop argument is deprecated since Python 3.8, and scheduled for removal in Python 3.10.`

Comment: Good catch. it should work fine without the argument, I only included it for flexibility.  I don't even use asyncio anymore, I always use trio.

Comment: At least the trio code, waits for Enter to process the input. This wouldn't work for a game loop for example, to get real-time keypress input.

Answer (score 11):

I wrote something similar as part of a package called [aioconsole](https://github.com/vxgmichel/aioconsole).

It provides a coroutine called `get_standard_streams` that returns two [asyncio streams](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#streams-coroutine-based-api) corresponding to `stdin` and `stdout`.

Here's an example:

```
import asyncio
import aioconsole

async def echo():
    stdin, stdout = await aioconsole.get_standard_streams()
    async for line in stdin:
        stdout.write(line)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(echo())
```

It also includes an asynchronous equivalent to `input`:

```
something = await aioconsole.ainput('Entrer something: ')
```

It should work for both file and non-file streams. See the implementation [here](https://github.com/vxgmichel/apython/blob/master/aioconsole/stream.py).

Comment: This waits for a new line. Is there a version that could work with a single keypress? or just one character?

Answer (score 9):

### Reading lines

The high-level pure-asyncio way to do this is as follows.

```
import asyncio
import sys

async def main():
        # Create a StreamReader with the default buffer limit of 64 KiB.
        reader = asyncio.StreamReader()
        pipe = sys.stdin
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        await loop.connect_read_pipe(lambda: asyncio.StreamReaderProtocol(reader), pipe)

        async for line in reader:
                print(f'Got: {line.decode()!r}')

asyncio.run(main())
```

The `async for line in reader` loop can be written more explicitly, e.g. if you want to print a prompt or catch exceptions inside the loop:

```
 while True:
            print('Prompt: ', end='', flush=True)
            try:
                line = await reader.readline()
                if not line:
                    break
            except ValueError:
                print('Line length went over StreamReader buffer limit.')
            else:
                print(f'Got: {line.decode()!r}')
```

An empty `line` (not `'\n'` but an actually empty string `''`) means end-of-file. Note that it is possible for `await reader.readline()` to return `''` right after `reader.at_eof()` returned False. See [Python asyncio: StreamReader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#streamreader) for details.

Here `readline()` is asynchronously gathering a line of input. That is, the event loop can run while the reader waits for more characters. In contrast, in the other answers, the event loop could block: it could detect that some input is available, enter the function calling `sys.stdin.readline()`, and then block on it until an endline becomes available (blocking any other tasks from entering the loop). Of course this isn't a problem in most cases, as the endline becomes available together with (in case of line buffering, which is the default) or very soon after (in other cases, assuming reasonably short lines) any initial characters of a line.

### Reading character by character

You can also read individual bytes with `await reader.readexactly(1)` to read byte-per-byte, when reading from a pipe. When reading key-presses from a terminal, it needs to be set up properly, see [Key Listeners in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11918999/key-listeners-in-python) for more. On UNIX:

```
import asyncio
import contextlib
import sys
import termios

@contextlib.contextmanager
def raw_mode(file):
    old_attrs = termios.tcgetattr(file.fileno())
    new_attrs = old_attrs[:]
    new_attrs[3] = new_attrs[3] & ~(termios.ECHO | termios.ICANON)
    try:
        termios.tcsetattr(file.fileno(), termios.TCSADRAIN, new_attrs)
        yield
    finally:
        termios.tcsetattr(file.fileno(), termios.TCSADRAIN, old_attrs)

async def main():
    with raw_mode(sys.stdin):
        reader = asyncio.StreamReader()
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        await loop.connect_read_pipe(lambda: asyncio.StreamReaderProtocol(reader), sys.stdin)

        while not reader.at_eof():
            ch = await reader.read(1)
            # '' means EOF, chr(4) means EOT (sent by CTRL+D on UNIX terminals)
            if not ch or ord(ch) <= 4:
                break
            print(f'Got: {ch!r}')

asyncio.run(main())
```

Note this is not really one character or one key at a time: if the user presses a key combination that gives a multi-byte character, like ALT+E, nothing will happen on pressing ALT and two bytes will be sent by the terminal on pressing E, which will result in two iterations of the loop. But it's good enough for ASCII characters like letters and ESC.

If you need actual key presses like ALT, I suppose the only way is to use [a suitable library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072790/detect-key-press-in-python) and make it work with asyncio by calling it in a separate thread, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58493467/asyncio-keyboard-input-that-can-be-canceled). In fact the library+thread approach is probably simpler in other cases as well.

### Under the hood

If you want finer control you can implement your own protocol in place of `StreamReaderProtocol`: a class implementing any number of functions of [`asyncio.Protocol`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-protocol.html). Minimal example:

```
class MyReadProtocol(asyncio.Protocol):
    def __init__(self, reader: asyncio.StreamReader):
        self.reader = reader

    def connection_made(self, pipe_transport):
        self.reader.set_transport(pipe_transport)

    def data_received(self, data: bytes):
        self.reader.feed_data(data)

    def connection_lost(self, exc):
        if exc is None:
            self.reader.feed_eof()
        else:
            self.reader.set_exception(exc)
```

You could replace the StreamReader with your own buffering mechanism. After you call `connect_read_pipe(lambda: MyReadProtocol(reader), pipe)`, there will be exactly one call to `connection_made`, then arbitrary many calls to `data_received` (with data depending on terminal and python buffering options), then eventually exactly one call to `connection_lost` (on end-of-file or on error). In case you ever need them, `connect_read_pipe` returns a tuple `(transport, protocol)`, where `protocol` is an instance of `MyReadProtocol` (created by the protocol factory, which in our case is a trivial lambda), while `transport` is an instance of `asyncio.ReadTransport` (specifically  some private implementation like `_UnixReadPipeTransport` on UNIX).

But in the end this is all boilerplate that eventually relies on [`loop.add_reader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.add_reader%60) (unrelated to `StreamReader`).

For Windows you might need to choose the `ProactorEventLoop` (the default since Python 3.8), see [Python asyncio: Platform Support](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-platforms.html).

Comment: Thanks for this very details answer - especially for the "Reading character by character", and thanks for the examples working out of the box. Seems to be the only spot where you can find this information (at least for me)

Comment: Thanks, listening to keystrokes asynchronously in "Reading character by character" was what I was looking for. This answer needs to be upvoted a lot.

Comment: Platform note: `connect_read_pipe` doesn't seem to work on Windows. This first example returns `AttributeError: '_ProactorReadPipeTransport' object has no attribute '_empty_waiter'` which appears to be a [open issue from 2016](https://bugs.python.org/issue26832).

Comment: Here's a solution that seems to work on Windows: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36785819/1174169

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to using queues would be to make the command line an asyn generator, and process the commands as they come in, like so:

```
import asyncio
import sys

class UserInterface(object):

def __init__(self, task, loop):
    self.task = task
    self.loop = loop

    def get_ui(self):
        return asyncio.ensure_future(self._ui_task())

    async def _ui_cmd(self):
        while True:
            cmd = sys.stdin.readline()
            cmd = cmd.strip()
            if cmd == 'exit':
                self.loop.stop()
                return
            yield cmd

    async def _ui_task(self):
        async for cmd in self._ui_cmd():
            if cmd == 'stop_t':
                self.task.stop()
            elif cmd == 'start_t':
                self.task.start()
```

Comment: This won't work as expected. `sys.stdin.readline` call will block the whole program (including other coroutines) until it gets line end.

Answer (score -1):

Python 3.10 update to the solution provided by [bj0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/618895/bj0):

```py
class Prompt:
    def __init__(self):
        self.loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
        self.q = asyncio.Queue()
        self.loop.add_reader(sys.stdin, self.got_input)

    def got_input(self):
        asyncio.ensure_future(self.q.put(sys.stdin.readline()), loop=self.loop)

    async def __call__(self, msg, end='\n', flush=False):
        print(msg, end=end, flush=flush)
        # https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#coroutine
        task = asyncio.create_task(self.q.get())
        return (await task).rstrip('\n')
```

I tested it on a websocket client, inside an async function that would get stuck waiting for input, so I replaced `s = input("insert string")` with `s = await prompt("insert string")` and now ping-ponging works even while the program is waiting for user input, the connection does not stop anymore and the issue "timed out waiting for keepalive pong" is solved.