# asyncssh - how to create listener while still getting user inputs

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am working with network equipment, i writing a program that uses asyncssh to do ssh to network device.

The network device sends sometimes updates via the session using broadcast.
What i am trying to do is to make a listener that listens to the stdout, and still can get user inputs (probably will be some sort of rest api functions).

Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Yes, that sounds plausible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This stack overflow answer shows you how to listen to stdin async:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35514777/10840818

Write some code. What are you trying to do? The following is the example from the asyncSSH docs. Is your question about asyncSSH or something else?

```
import asyncio, asyncssh, sys

async def run_client():
    async with asyncssh.connect('localhost') as conn:
        result = await conn.run('echo "Hello!"', check=True)
        print(result.stdout, end='')

try:
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(run_client())
except (OSError, asyncssh.Error) as exc:
    sys.exit('SSH connection failed: ' + str(exc))
```

If you need a server process look at sanic and set up a rest API instead of stdin for communicating.