# Asyncio keyboard input that can be canceled

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm trying to write a concurrent Python program using `asyncio` that also accepts keyboard input.  The problem appears when I try to shut down my program.  Since keyboard input is in the end done with `sys.stdin.readline`, that function only returns after I press `ENTER`, regardless if I `stop()` the event loop or `cancel()` the function's `Future`.

Is there any way to provide keyboard input with `asyncio` that can be canceled?

Here is my MWE.  It will accept keyboard inputs for 1 second, then `stop()`:

```
import asyncio
import sys

async def console_input_loop():
    while True:
        inp = await loop.run_in_executor(None, sys.stdin.readline)
        print(f"[{inp.strip()}]")

async def sleeper():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("stop")
    loop.stop()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.create_task(console_input_loop())
loop.create_task(sleeper())
loop.run_forever()
```

Comment: You’ll have to avoid readline, given that it does exactly what you say, i.e. waits for enter, and you want your keyboard input not to wait for enter. What else have you tried.

Comment: @barny: there are not many options. I tried `input()` as well as `msvcrt.getwch()`. Same effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the executor insists on ensuring that all running futures have completed by the time the program terminates. But in this case you actually want an "unclean" termination because there's no portable way of canceling an on-going `read()` or of accessing `sys.stdin` asynchronously.

Canceling the future has no effect because [`concurrent.futures.Future.cancel`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future.cancel) is a no-op once its callback has started executing. The best way to avoid the unwanted waiting is to avoid `run_in_executor` in the first place and just spawn your own thread:

```
async def ainput():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    fut = loop.create_future()
    def _run():
        line = sys.stdin.readline()
        loop.call_soon_threadsafe(fut.set_result, line)
    threading.Thread(target=_run, daemon=True).start()
    return await fut
```

The thread is created manually and marked as "daemon", so no one will wait for it at program shutdown. As a result, a variant of the code that uses `ainput` instead of `run_in_executor(sys.stdin.readline)` terminates as expected:

```
async def console_input_loop():
    while True:
        inp = await ainput()
        print(f"[{inp.strip()}]")

# rest of the program unchanged
```

Comment: This question has been asked so many times on this site and this is my favorite answer so far. Running the input in another thread seems to be the only way to truly abort the blocking readline().