# How to keep a python script idle without using too many ressources

Tags: python-3.x, background-process, idle-processing

Basically the title, i have a small python script (python 3.9, Windows 10) that i would like to keep running in the background. It is currently listening for keyboard hotkeys and acting like a macro engine. I want it to stay idle, since i use the keyboard module so i doesnt need to call anything, just wait.
 I tried a while loop with either `pass` or `sleep` in it, but both have downsides, the one with `pass` using a lot of cpu ressources, and the one with `sleep` being very unreliable.

Is there any pretty/good practice way of doing this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use some library that does the trick for you.

For example you can try Asyncio:

```
import asyncio 

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
try:
    loop.run_forever()
finally:
    loop.close()
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35223896/listen-to-keypress-with-asyncio)'s an Asyncio example for keypress.

Comment: Hello, did you have a moment to check my reply? If it was useful for you please consider upvoting it and / or choosing it as final answer. Thanks for your time!