# Get string typed in input after screen reset

Tags: python, websocket

I have a websocket chat-application. The user can send and receive messages simultaneously. The problem I had however is that because it is a CLI application the input-line of the user got messed up with the incoming messages.

You would have something like:

```
Message: Hello
Type message: Hi
Message: How are you
```

I want to have the input-field for the user always below the 'chat-screen'.

```
Message: Hello
Message: How are you

Type message: Hi
```

I have achieved this by putting all the received messages in a list. When a new message is received the screen gets emptied and the content of the chat-list is displayed. After looping over the chat-list, we display the input-field again. This works fine.

**The problem I have:** When the user is typing a message in the input-field, and while he is typing a message comes in the screen gets emptied to display the chat. But also the message he was typing in the input-field gets emptied.

```
# Chat session
Hello
How are you

Type message: Hi, I am o

# Message comes in > screen gets emptied to display chat again > user-input is also emptied
Hello
How are you
Test

Type message:

# Wanted behavior (The message the user was typing is still visible in input-field)
Hello
How are you
Test

Type message: Hi, I am oka
```

**Note:** What is interesting though. Is that when the screen and the input gets emptied and the user presses enter. The message typed before emptying is still send. Which means that Python must save the entered string somewhere in a buffer.

**Current behavior (Input gets reset during incoming message):**

[image: Current behavior]

**Wanted behavior (Input progress gets saved during incoming message):**

[image: Wanted behavior]

And like I said. Even if the screen gets emptied, pressing enter results in content of the input-field before emptying being sent. So Python must have a buffer somewhere containing the string. Could I use some kind of stream or stdin buffer to retrieve the message?

**Code:**

```py
import sys
import asyncio
import aioconsole

chat = []

async def start():
    sendTask = asyncio.ensure_future(send())
    receiveTask = asyncio.ensure_future(receiveSimulator())

    await asyncio.gather(sendTask, receiveTask)

async def send():
    while True:
        # Here I somehow need to capture the input of the user
        # even if he hasn't pressed enter
        sys.stdout.flush()
        sys.stdout.write("Type message: ")
        message = await aioconsole.ainput("")
        # Note that when the user sends a message, it is not directly
        # inputted in the chat. But first send to the server who
        # echo's it. Hence why we simulate it by calling receive
        receive(message)

def receive(message, sim = False):
    chat.append(message)
    reset_chat_screen(sim = sim)

# This function is purely to simulate a incoming message
async def receiveSimulator():
    await asyncio.sleep(8)
    receive("Incoming message", sim = True)

def reset_chat_screen(sim = False):
    # Empty screen
    print(chr(27) + "[2J")

    # Show all messages including new incoming one
    for message in chat:
        print(message)
  
    # Here I somehow need to put the captured input before the screen was emptied
    # e.g: sys.stdout.write("Type message: " + captured_input)
    if sim:
        sys.stdout.write("Type message: I am oka")
    else:
        sys.stdout.write("Type message: ")
    sys.stdout.flush()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start())
```

Comment: maybe you need function `getchat` or [getch](https://pypi.org/project/getch/) which get single char so you can run it in loop and keep every char in variable - and later you could use it to display message again. Or maybe you need module [curse](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html), `ncurse` or [rich](https://github.com/Textualize/rich) to better control screen. See also [textual](https://github.com/Textualize/textual)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35223896/listen-to-keypress-with-asyncio) I was able to find a solution.

This is my function to get the user input:

```py
@contextlib.contextmanager
def raw_mode(file):
    old_attrs = termios.tcgetattr(file.fileno())
    new_attrs = old_attrs[:]
    new_attrs[3] = new_attrs[3] & ~(termios.ECHO | termios.ICANON)
    try:
        termios.tcsetattr(file.fileno(), termios.TCSADRAIN, new_attrs)
        yield
    finally:
        termios.tcsetattr(file.fileno(), termios.TCSADRAIN, old_attrs)

async def get_user_input():
    with raw_mode(sys.stdin):
        global user_input

        reader = asyncio.StreamReader()
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        await loop.connect_read_pipe(lambda: asyncio.StreamReaderProtocol(reader), sys.stdin)

        while not reader.at_eof():
            ch = await reader.read(1)

            if ch == b'\n' or ch == '\r':
                r = user_input
                user_input = ""
                return r
            elif ch == b'\x7f':
                user_input = user_input[:-1]
                sys.stdout.write('\b \b')
                sys.stdout.flush()
            else:
                user_input += ch.decode('utf-8')
                sys.stdout.write(ch.decode('utf-8'))
                sys.stdout.flush()
```

In my `send()` function retrieve the user input like this:

```py
async def send():
    while True:

        message = await get_user_input()


        # Note that when the user sends a message, it is not directly
        # inputted in the chat. But first send to the server who
        # echo's it. Hence why we simulate it by calling receive
        receive(message)
```

In `reset_chat_screen` you can call

```
    sys.stdout.write("> " + user_input)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

`user_input` is a global variable.