# Avoid global variables for unpicklable shared state among multiprocessing.Pool workers

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, fork, python-multiprocessing

I frequently find myself writing programs in Python that construct a large (megabytes) read-only data structure and then use that data structure to analyze a very large (hundreds of megabytes in total) list of small records.  Each of the records can be analyzed in parallel, so a natural pattern is to set up the read-only data structure and assign it to a global variable, then create a [`multiprocessing.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool) (which implicitly copies the data structure into each worker process, via `fork`) and then use `imap_unordered` to crunch the records in parallel.  The skeleton of this pattern tends to look like this:

```
classifier = None
def classify_row(row):
    return classifier.classify(row)

def classify(classifier_spec, data_file):
    global classifier
    try:
        classifier = Classifier(classifier_spec)
        with open(data_file, "rt") as fp, \
             multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
            rd = csv.DictReader(fp)
            yield from pool.imap_unordered(classify_row, rd)
    finally:
        classifier = None
```

I'm not happy with this because of the global variable and the implicit coupling between `classify` and `classify_row`.  Ideally, I would like to write

```
def classify(classifier_spec, data_file):
    classifier = Classifier(classifier_spec)
    with open(data_file, "rt") as fp, \
         multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
        rd = csv.DictReader(fp)
        yield from pool.imap_unordered(classifier.classify, rd)
```

but this does not work, because the Classifier object usually contains objects which cannot be pickled (because they are defined by extension modules whose authors didn't care about that); I have also read that it would be really slow if it did work, because the Classifier object would get copied into the worker processes on *every invocation* of the bound method.

Is there a better alternative?  I only care about 3.x.

Answer (score 6):

This was surprisingly tricky. The key here is to preserve read-access to variables that are available at fork-time without serialization. Most solutions to sharing memory in multiprocessing end up serializing. I tried using a `weakref.proxy` to pass in a classifier without serialization, but that didn't work because both dill and pickle will try to follow and serialize the referent. *However*, a module-ref works.

This organization gets us close:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import csv


def classify(classifier, data_file):

    with open(data_file, "rt") as fp, mp.Pool() as pool:
        rd = csv.DictReader(fp)
        yield from pool.imap_unordered(classifier.classify, rd)


def orchestrate(classifier_spec, data_file):
    # construct a classifier from the spec; note that we can
    # even dynamically import modules here, using config values
    # from the spec
    import classifier_module
    classifier_module.init(classifier_spec)
    return classify(classifier_module, data_file)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    list(orchestrate(None, 'data.txt'))
```

A few changes to note here:

- we add an `orchestrate` method for some DI goodness; orchestrate figures out how to construct/initialize a classifier, and hands it to `classify`, decoupling the two
- `classify` only needs to assume that the `classifier` parameter has a `classify` method; it doesn't care if it's an instance or a module

For this Proof of Concept, we provide a Classifier that is obviously not serializable:

```
# classifier_module.py
def _create_classifier(spec):

    # obviously not pickle-able because it's inside a function
    class Classifier():

        def __init__(self, spec):
            pass

        def classify(self, x):
            print(x)
            return x

    return Classifier(spec)


def init(spec):
    global __classifier
    __classifier = _create_classifier(spec)


def classify(x):
    return __classifier.classify(x)
```

Unfortunately, there's still a global in here, but it's now nicely encapsulated inside a module as a private variable, and the module exports a tight interface composed of the `classify` and `init` functions.

This design unlocks some possibilities:

- `orchestrate` can import and init different classifier modules, based on what it sees in `classifier_spec`
- one could also pass an instance of some `Classifier` class to `classify`, as long as this instance is serializable and has a classify method of the same signature

Comment: Note this design only works if Classifier remains a singleton since a second instantiation would override the data.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use forking, I don't see a way around using a global. But I also don't see a reason why you would have to feel bad about using a global in this case, you're not manipulating a global list with multi-threading or so.

It's possible to cope with the ugliness in your example, though. You want to pass `classifier.classify` directly, but the `Classifier` object contains objects which cannot be pickled.

```
import os
import csv
import uuid
from threading import Lock
from multiprocessing import Pool
from weakref import WeakValueDictionary

class Classifier:

    def __init__(self, spec):
        self.lock = Lock()  # unpickleable
        self.spec = spec

    def classify(self, row):
        return f'classified by pid: {os.getpid()} with spec: {self.spec}', row
```

I suggest we subclass `Classifier` and define `__getstate__` and `__setstate__` to enable pickling. Since you're using forking anyway, all state it has to pickle, is information how to get a reference to a forked global instance. Then we'll just update the pickled object's `__dict__` with the `__dict__` of the forked instance (which hasn't gone through the reduction of pickling) and your instance is complete again.

To achieve this without additional boilerplate, the subclassed `Classifier` instance has to generate a name for itself and register this as a global variable. This first reference, will be a weak reference, so the instance can be garbage collected when the user expects it. The second reference is created by the user when he assigns `classifier = Classifier(classifier_spec)`. This one, doesn't have to be global.

The generated name in the example below is generated with help of standard-lib's `uuid` module. An uuid is converted to a string and edited into a valid identifier (it wouldn't have to be, but it's convenient for debugging in interactive mode).

```
class SubClassifier(Classifier):

    def __init__(self, spec):
        super().__init__(spec)
        self.uuid = self._generate_uuid_string()
        self.pid = os.getpid()
        self._register_global()

    def __getstate__(self):
        """Define pickled content."""
        return {'uuid': self.uuid}

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        """Set state in child process."""
        self.__dict__ = state
        self.__dict__.update(self._get_instance().__dict__)

    def _get_instance(self):
        """Get reference to instance."""
        return globals()[self.uuid][self.uuid]

    @staticmethod
    def _generate_uuid_string():
        """Generate id as valid identifier."""
        # return 'uuid_' + '123' # for testing
        return 'uuid_' + str(uuid.uuid4()).replace('-', '_')

    def _register_global(self):
        """Register global reference to instance."""
        weakd = WeakValueDictionary({self.uuid: self})
        globals().update({self.uuid: weakd})

    def __del__(self):
        """Clean up globals when deleted in parent."""
        if os.getpid() == self.pid:
            globals().pop(self.uuid)
```

The sweet thing here is, the boilerplate is totally gone. You don't have to mess manually with declaring and deleting globals since the instance manages everything itself in background:

```
def classify(classifier_spec, data_file, n_workers):
    classifier = SubClassifier(classifier_spec)
    # assert globals()['uuid_123']['uuid_123'] # for testing
    with open(data_file, "rt") as fh, Pool(n_workers) as pool:
        rd = csv.DictReader(fh)
        yield from pool.imap_unordered(classifier.classify, rd)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    PATHFILE = 'data.csv'
    N_WORKERS = 4

    g = classify(classifier_spec='spec1', data_file=PATHFILE, n_workers=N_WORKERS)
    for record in g:
        print(record)

   # assert 'uuid_123' not in globals() # no reference left
```

Answer (score -1):

The [`multiprocessing.sharedctypes`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.sharedctypes) module provides functions for allocating ctypes objects from shared memory which can be inherited by child processes, i.e., parent and children can access the shared memory.

You could use
1. `multiprocessing.sharedctypes.RawArray` to allocate a ctypes array from the shared memory.
2. `multiprocessing.sharedctypes.RawValue` to allocate a ctypes object from the shared memory.

Dr Mianzhi Wang has written a [very detailed document](https://research.wmz.ninja/articles/2018/03/on-sharing-large-arrays-when-using-pythons-multiprocessing.html) on this. You could share multiple `multiprocessing.sharedctypes` objects.

You may find the [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52495824/) useful to you.